# Spring gateway monitoring UI

Tags: spring, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using spring cloud gateway as my api management tool deployed in kubernetes. Is there any UI tool which I can  integrate with the gateway to monitor the health, transactions, the messages flowing in and out etc

Comment: Spring Boot Admin provides a UI if you want to use it I may answer the question

Comment: elastic-apm -> kibana